# FTP upload with full permission (CHMOD 777)

Tags: perl, ftp

I want to create a directory and upload file in a remote server through PERL FTP function. Everything works fine except I can't upload them with CHMOD 777. Is it something that I can change by command, or it will be determined by the user access level?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Net::FTP;
my $ftp=Net::FTP->new($server);
$ftp->login($user, $password);
$ftp->binary();
$ftp->mkdir($outputdir);
$chmod     = "chmod 777 $outputdir";
$ftp->cmd($chmod);
$ftp->cwd($outputdir);
$ftp->put($file);
my $chmod     = "chmod 777 $file";
$ftp->cmd($chmod);
$ftp->quit;
```

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish, `chmod 777` is almost certainly wrong. You don't usually want files to be world-writable.

Comment: yaa, I know .. so did I tell .. but anyhow it is the server owner's request, and so i don't bother actually ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to get the response of the server to your chmod command, e.g. use `$ftp->code` and `$ftp->message` or simply enable debugging.  Here you would probably see that the server does not understand your command.

The reason might be, that you use `$ftp->cmd` to execute this command. But, `cmd` is used to send an FTP command, and chmod is no FTP command. To execute any command on the site of the server you should instead use `site`, e.g. `$ftp->site("chmod ....")`. And even here you should check the results, because the server is not required to honor your request and to execute any commands you want.

In summary: always check error messages. Apart from that: please `use strict` on any perl scripts.